# Spring Kafka. Non-blocking retries - topics are created even when autoCreateTopics property is false

Tags: spring-kafka

I am trying to implement non-blocking retries for my project using spring-kafka 2.8.0 with non-blocking retry feature.

I have done the following. autoCreateTopics property is false!

```
    @KafkaListener(
            id = "customListenerId",
            idIsGroup = false,
            topics = "main-topic-1, main-topic-2")
    @RetryableTopic(
            autoCreateTopics = "false",
            fixedDelayTopicStrategy = FixedDelayStrategy.SINGLE_TOPIC,
            backoff = @Backoff(delay = 10000),
            attempts = "6",
            kafkaTemplate = "kafkaTemplate",
            include = {
                    AerospikeException.Timeout.class,
                    QueryTimeoutException.class,
                    HystrixRuntimeException.class})
    public void consumePerTopic(@Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) String topic,
                                @Payload byte[] payload,
                                Acknowledgment acknowledgment) {
        processor.process(objectMapper.readValue(payload, CreateRequest.class));
        acknowledgment.acknowledge();
    }
```

I got the following integration test for it which uses kafka as embedded container.
Test simulates db connection issues - code under test must throw AerospikeException.Timeout which is declared as retryable in consumer.

```
@Test
    void shouldNotCreateEntityForTopicsWhenDbTimedOutAndProduceRetryMessages() {
        performWithDbLatency(Duration.ofMillis(1000), () -> {
            var createEntityIdempotencyKeys = entityKafkaSteps.sendCreateRequestToAllTopicsWithIdempotency(
                    getCreateEntityRequest("entity-owner-a"));

            retryEntityKafkaSteps.consumeRetryCreateRequestsByIdempotencyKeys(createEntityIdempotencyKeys);
        });
    }
```

My configuration for embedded kafka container looks like

```
embedded:
  kafka:
    topicsToCreate: main-topic-1, main-topic-2
```

I understand that the default behaviour of kafka is to allow auto topics creation.
This test is passing successfully, but as I understand autoCreateTopics property should block retry and dlt topics creation even if it is allowed in kafka broker -> and test must fail because there is no retry and dlt topics in broker.

Please clarify is it an expected behaviour or not, or whether I am missing something?
The same behaviour is present if to declare retry functionality via RetryTopicConfiguration bean using *doNotAutoCreateRetryTopics()* method.

Thanks a lot.

**Edited** :
My main concern is:

1. I forbid spring-kafka to create retry and dlt topics for my consumer for *main-topic-1* and *main-topic-2* using `autoCreateTopics = "false"`.
2. I create **ONLY** *main-topic-1* and *main-topic-2* in my embedded kafka container using `embedded.kafka.topicsToCreate` property. (Kafka broker default property is `allow.auto.create.topics = true`)
3. On runtime I can see that *main-topic-1-retry*, *main-topic-1-dlt*, *main-topic-2-retry* and *main-topic-2-dlt* are still created.

I am using [playtika test containers library](https://github.com/Playtika/testcontainers-spring-boot/blob/develop/embedded-kafka/README.adoc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No `autoCreateTopics = "false"` simply means that the framework will not create the topics; it has no bearing on whether the broker is configured to create them.

`@EmbeddedKafka(topics = ...)` will always create the topics.

To disable topic creation in the embedded kafka broker, use

`@EmbeddedKafka(brokerProperties = "auto.create.topics.enable:false")`

and don't specify any `topics` there.

Or you can set the consumer property `allow.auto.create.topics` to `false`; it overrides the broker property (if it is true).

https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs_allow.auto.create.topics

Comment: Thanks for reply, yes you are totally right, but when I specify `autoCreateTopics = "false"`  in my consumer - _retry_ and _dlt_ topics are still created, is it an expected behaviour?

Comment: They will be created unless the broker is configured to NOT auto create topics. As I said, that setting tells the framework not to create them; it can't control what the broker does.

Comment: Sorry, but let me clarify - broker creates only main topic, and I specify it in `emebedded.kafka.topicsToCreate` property, but I do not specify here to create retry and dlt topics for that main topic, however framework does it still, even when `autoCreateTopics = "false"`.  Broker does create only main topic, framework `autoCreateTopics = "false"` and framework still creates retry and dlt topics for main topic. Why does it happen?

Comment: Please show your embedded kafka test configuration (edit the question and comment here that you have done so). The embedded broker will create the main topic because you have told it to; the broker itself will create the others when the consumers are started (unless `auto.create.topics.enable` is `false`).

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question and introduced more details

Comment: One more time - you have to set `allow.auto.create.topics` to false to prevent the broker creating the topic when the consumer connects; or you can set the consumer property  `allow.auto.create.topics` https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs_allow.auto.create.topics to false.

Answer (score 0):

@Gary Russel thanks a lot for your patience - I have finally understood the root cause. Topics are created not by the spring-kafka, but by the consumer which connects to retry and dlt topics in my test -> broker allows it to do it -> topics are auto created.

Thanks for you help!